# ArcMap: How to change mouse pointer to an arrow in Mapview - VB.NET

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vb.net

I'm writing a add-in for ArcMap 10.5 in VB.NET. I've chosen the item "Button". So when I click on the button I need the mouse pointer, when in MapView, to turn into an arrow (like the Select Feature arrow). Right now it only turns into the Pan (hand).

This is how my current code looks like:

```
Public Class btnMatareIdentify
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button

    Public Sub OnClick(ByVal cursorID As Object)

        Dim app As IApplication
        Dim appCursor As IMouseCursor = New MouseCursorClass

        Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
        Dim pActiveView As IActiveView

        pMxDoc = My.Document
        pActiveView = pMxDoc.ActiveView

        If TypeOf pActiveView IsNot IPageLayout Then
            appCursor.SetCursor(0) 
            myMethod()
        Else
            MsgBox("You need to be in MapMode")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see here for using the IMouseCursor method to display other cursors:

[IMouseCursor Help 10.5](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/10.5/net/webframe.htm#IMouseCursor_SetCursor.htm)

Be aware that the cursor will return to the default as soon as the calling procedure ends.

That being said I'm wondering what you are trying to achieve here? Usually a button just executes some action and then ends so you wouldn't change the cursor to anything but a wait cursor. Depending on what you want to do a Tool might be what you are looking for. It has a property for the cursor and when activated it displays that cursor.

[Create a Custom Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/10.5/net/webframe.htm#ec9c3bf9-1bae-4d56-9ae6-e439dbd0f18f.htm#createADrawGraphicLineTool)